# SQL - select conflicting values only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns [SQL Server 2008 R2]

- `LastName`
- `DOB`
- `Zip`
- `Address`
- `Phone`
- `Email`

I need to find all the same (`LastName`, `DOB`, `Zip`, `Address`) having conflicting `Phone` and `Email` and with an edit distance of the conflicts.

I already have a UDF for `edit_distance` but I am unable to come up with a query.

Note: There can be more than two duplicates in my table.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
select *
from table t join
     table t2
     on t.lastname = t2.lastname and t.dob = t2.dob and
        t.zip = t2.zip and t.address = t2.zip
where edit_distance(t.phone, t2.phone) > @threshhold or
      edit_distance(t.email, t2.email) > @threshhold;
```

Comment: Thanks, I apologize for not sharing enough details in my original post. This works well except in cases where I have more than 2 duplicates. i.e. more than 2 (LastName, DOB, Zip, Address)

Comment: @user3726933 Then state in the question how you want more than 2 duplicates handled.

Comment: @Blam I could have done better but assuming duplicates = 2 is also not very intuitive. Question edited.

Comment: @user3726933 So you can have more duplicates > 2.  You have not stated how you want that handled?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a self join.

```
select t1.*, edit_distance(t1.Phone, t2.Phone) EditDistancePhone, edit_distance(t1.Email, t2.Email)EditDistanceEmail from 
(select LastName, DOB, Zip, Address, Phone, Email from Table1) t1
inner join 
(select LastName, DOB, Zip, Address, Phone, Email from Table1) t2
on t1.LastName = t2.LastName
and t1.DOB = t2.DOB
and t1.Zip = t2.Zip
and t1.Address = t2.Address
and t1.Phone <> t2.Phone
and t1.Email <> t2.Email
```

More details on the UDF would definitely help people here in giving better answers.